# Xamarin Forms ConstraintExpressions - Can i do expressions in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a horizontal Listview but to center it on any device i would have to set the XConstraint and the YConstraint to:`(ParentWidth * 0.5) - (ParentHeight * 0.5)`

Is there any way of doing this in Xaml or does this have to be done in code ?

Best I could come up with was this (I am an Xamarin rookie):

```
1. RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant={ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}}"
```

or :

```
2. RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5} - {ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.5} "
```